# zsh `time` doesn't work with `source`

Tags: zsh

I can use `time` to get running time statistics:

```
% time zsh --version
zsh 5.6.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
zsh --version  0.00s user 0.00s system 86% cpu 0.005 total
```

How can I time how long a source script takes to run?

```
% time source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `zsh` does not support to time builtin commands.

Try to use a shell that includes support for `time` as a reserved word (this applies to `zsh`) **and** also supports to time builtin commands (this does not apply to `zsh`).

BTW: this works for `ksh88`, `ksh93`, `bosh` (the current Bourne Shell), `mksh`  and `bash`.

BTW: The correct way to do timing is to take the timing for the shell and all it's sub procecces (that may be called programs) and to print the difference from before and after the command. If the timing includes the time spent in the shell itself, this allows to time builtin commands.

The background is that the timing that works inside the shell should be compatible to what the external `time` command does and the external `time` command prints the sum of all times of all processes created for a specific command. If `time` did not include the values for sub processes, it would e.g. print too low values for the command `cc` as most of the work is done inside sub processes of `cc`.

Comment: It can only time processes. So `time (source ...)` or `time (echo x)` would work. Other shells may end up including the times of other processes when timing builtins or functions. See for instance `bosh -c 'seq 10000000 > /dev/null & time read'` that includes the user/sys time of `seq` if you press enter after `seq` has returned. IIRC mksh has some improvements on that front.

Comment: This is a corner case. Not including sub processes when timing functions and builtins is also wrong. So you have to decide what is worse,  being wrong in most cases or being wrong in some rare corner cases.

Comment: `zsh` includes sub-processes when timing functions which you have to time with `time (myfunction)`. `zsh` is right  for all the times it reports.

Comment: See how `/usr/bin/time /bin/echo $(find / | wc -l)` report something different from `time /bin/echo $(find / | wc -l)` in all shells that have a `time` keyword except `zsh`.

Comment: What you describe as _the correct way_ is wrong. A more correct way (which IIRC is the one implemented by mksh) would be to take the times before and after but substract the times of the child processes that are not part of the pipeline. In any case, the time of the child processes that have been started as part of the pipeline but haven't finished yet by the time the pipeline returns is not accounted for and cannot be. (typical in `bash` for things like `time { cmd  >(cmd2); }` which generally fails to account `cmd2`'s time (even `time (cmd  >(cmd2))` fails, `zsh` is OK).

Comment: What you describe (keeping track of other process group times) is something that currently cannot be done in `bosh` as `bosh` does not implement a `SIGCHLD` handler and as `bosh` does not yet implement a list of recently finished job status data. `bosh` implements a similar method as `csh` and in all but a few corner cases reports better timing that other POSIX like shells do. With regards to your previous example: `/usr/bin/time` cannot see the times from the command substitution, but `ksh88` already defines that the whole command is to be timed with the `keyword time`, so `zsh` is wrong.

Comment: that zsh two shells have different APIs doesn't make any of them wrong. See how zsh reports both the times of `cmd1` and `cmd2` in `cmd1 | cmd2`. ksh doesn't do it, that doesn't mean it's wrong as it's not ksh's intention to reproduce the zsh behaviour.

Comment: OK, but why should there be a builtin variant of `time` in the shell if you don't get any advantages from that fact?

Comment: You do get an advantage. `time foo | bar` is much more useful in `zsh` than with the non-builtin `time` (or the `time` of other shells), it's also got it's `TIMEFMT` format à la csh, and you can time functions and builtins or compound commands (as long as you remember to put them in subshells, which I'll grant you, is somewhat of a limitation compared to ksh/bash but at least means it's reliable) which you can't do with an external `time`.

Comment: The features with `TIMEFORMAT` in `bosh` are more useful than what you get with `zsh` in special as `bosh` supports up to microsecond granularity for the times and `zsh` usually just prints `0.00` for the timing of e.g. `ls -l`. I recommend you to try out the `TIMEFORMAT` sample value from the `bosh` man page.

Comment: You can use `%*U` for instance on zsh to get millisecond precision, but getting that much precision (anything smaller than a scheduler typical time slice) doesn't make that much sense. If you want to time an operation with some level of precision, you'll be better off doing things like `time (repeat 10000 that-operation)` and take the average IMO. For elapsed time, you can also use `typeset -F SECONDS` like in ksh93 or use `$EPOCHREALTIME` to get nanoseconds, but again, that much precision doesn't make that much sense in shells that deal with commands having to be run in separate processes.

Comment: Well I usually work on Solaris and the Solaris kernel implements micro state accounting (since approx. 15 years) that produces reliable microsecond values. So `bosh` gives you what you need for you need for performance mesurement.

Comment: Yet as an illustration, testing `bosh -c 'TIMEFORMAT=%6U; time ls'` on a Solaris 11.4 VM here, I get `0.001383` on the first run, `0.000907` on the second, `0.001173` on the 3rd. It seems 1 ms is enough precision. `/usr/bin/time bosh -c 'TIMEFORMAT=%6U; c=0; time while [ "$c" -lt 1000 ]; do ls; c=$(($c+1)); done'` has bosh report `0.836859` user time while `/usr/bin/time` reports `0.0` user time. Might be something wrong with /usr/bin/time there. It also looks as if the zsh build on that machine doesn't account time of children processes.

Comment: The precision inside the kernel is really nanoseconds. With `ptime` you get that resolution, but note there are variations  from many sources e,g, interrupt scheduling and the time spent in the scheduler is not always the same. In multi user mode and with more  CPUs, there is another imprecision... You get less variation if you write a CPU bound application and lock it to a specific CPU. You believe the results depend on the clock interrupt rate from the scheduler, so expect a variation of 10ms. I however only see a variation of approx. 100usec. It is better than what I get from Linux.